# Is there a term that indicates the relationship between myself and the mother of my grandchild who is no longer in a relationship with my son?

Tags: expressions, kinship-terms

My son & the mother of my grandchild were never married. They are no longer a couple but enjoy a very comfortable co-parenting relationship. When they broke up she and I did not! Although she was never my official daughter-in-law, that is the type of relationship we had and continue to have. Introducing her is always painful. She was never my daughter-in-law so she isn't my ex daughter-in-law - and even if she were that term is not acceptable to me -- she isn't *my* ex.  The only phrases I am even partially comfortable with are "______'s Mom" and "the mother of my grandchild." It explains the blood-line, but it just doesn't capture the spirit of our bond. Are there words from other languages that might express the spirit of this relationship?

Comment: Not only your relation with her but also your son's was an illegitimate one. Even if it were a legitimate one, she would have been only your daughter-in-law, not daughter. For your grandchild, the relation with both her and your son is not by law but by birth. For her you are her child's grandpa, that is a blood-bond; but for you she is none by blood or law. Nothing more touching than the term your "----'s Mom"!

Comment: @mahmudkoya Sorry, but calling the relationship "illegitimate" comes off as either judgemental or old-fashioned.

Comment: Privately, could you say she is your son's ex?

Comment: @Cascabel, sorry if my usage illegitimate is untimely. I meant it so from the law's perspective only. By law, the maximum it could have been only a father in law - daughter in law relation. In real scenario, if we termed something like " daughter-out-law", how cruel it would be!

Comment: "My grandson's mother" seems to me to be the most suitable phrase.

Comment: What did you call her when your son and she were together?  As you say, she is not your ex, so you can call her what you always called her.  And she can call you what she always called you, even Mom.

Comment: As a comment, since I cannot speak to the question of words in other languages. When I was a child my father took up with a woman and they are, after so many years "common-law." But during those early years, my sibling and I simply referred to her children as "step-brother" etc. in conversation, because, really, the details are cumbersome and unimportant. You might simply say: "this is my ex-daughter-in-law and good friend," which is to the point and finishes with the important bit.

Comment: @mahmudkoya the expression *illegitimate* has very negative connotations in English (not only)  and using this expression for long term romantic relationships *does* sound judgmental to English native speakers. To say to any grandparent, but especially to a grandmother, that their grandchild was fruit of an illegitimate relation  is insensitive, and frankly untrue. It is not "illegitimate"  to live with a same sex partner, or a hetereosexual couple  and for them to grow a family. The law (in the west) does not demand that children be born in wedlock.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, (illegitimate:(of a child) born of parents not lawfully married to each other.https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/illegitimate). The OP certifies it by his own words: "My son & the mother of my grandchild were never married". I have already explained my views on having used that word. I've also said, "Nothing more touching than the term your "----'s Mom!" I'm ready to delete it, if it's that much disgusting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I would like also to know from  you in this context, what  a legitimate or an illegitimate relation is and who a legitimate or an illegitimate child is.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Note that the OP did not use the term *illegitimate* to describe the relationship between her son and the mother of her grandchild, precisely because it has very negative connotations. The expression "bastard child" used to be common, it was used in law courts but  then it became an insult, and it is now considered, rightly so, derogatory. Although the term illegitimate is listed in the dictionary, it is not acceptable to call any child that name. Not outside of a law of justice, in any case.

Comment: The relationship between two consenting adults was not illegitimate. There is no law prohibiting two adults to have a sexual romantic relationship. This discussion is doomed to get overlong and complicated. I am merely explaining in greater detail what might have prompted  Cascabel's  comment.

Answer (score 5):

The OP asks about terms in other languages that might define her relationship with the mother of her grandchild.  That is beyond the scope of ELU and my knowledge, but I can say with confidence that there is no *English* word or term for the OP's situation.  English does not have an elaborate suite of words to describe complicated family relationships.

What English speakers (at least in much of the US) do is simplify, co-opt or make up terms to express not blood or legal relationships, but emotional relationships.

For example, my mother's best friend was Auntie Helen (later Aunt Helen) to me and everyone in our circle knew that.  "Will your Auntie Helen be at your recital?"

As another example, a friend calls a woman who was close to him and his family when he was growing up "my other mother".  I'm not sure of the actual relationship -- sister or cousin of one of his parents or maybe his mother's closest friend -- but it doesn't matter; she was his "other mother" and the listener would have to be dense indeed not to infer the love he felt for her, and her closeness to his entire family.

Thus, the OP can call this young woman whatever both feel comfortable with, and is not *required* to explain anything, although she may occasionally want to.

There's only one circumstance I can think of where the OP might have to back off from a title that implies a legal family relationship: if the young lady is in hospital and the docs are seeking permission for a medical procedure from a family member.  Other than that, it is really no one's business but yours and the mother of your grandchild.